# Prove that at least one of the expressions does not exceed $\sqrt[3]{3}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $m,n > 1$ be positive integers. Prove that at least one of the numbers $$\sqrt[n]{m} \ , \ \sqrt[m]{n}$$ does not exceed $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

I thought about doing a proof by contradiction. That is, assume this is not the case and so both exceed $\sqrt[3]{3}$. Then, $\sqrt[n]{m} > \sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\sqrt[m]{n} > \sqrt[3]{3}$. How do we continue?

Comment: What is if $m=n\ge4$

Comment: Nevermind, thought $\sqrt[2]{2}>\sqrt[3]{3}$ :) @user19405892

Answer (score 7):

Without loss of generality, assume that $m\ge n$. Then $$\sqrt[m]{n} \le \sqrt[n]{n}$$

We just want to show that $$\sqrt[n]{n} \le \sqrt[3]{3}, $$
which is equivalent to 
     $$n^3 \le 3^n.$$

This is not hard by,   for example, proof by induction.

When $n=2$ or $3$, this is true, and when $n > 3$, $$n^3 = (n-1)^3 + 3(n-1)^2+ 3(n-1) + 1  \le (n-1)^3 + (n-1)^3 + 3(n-1) + 1 = 2(n-1)^3 + 3n -2 < 2(n-1)^3 + (n-1)^3 = 3(n-1)^3 \le 3*3^{n-1} = 3^n$$

If you want to use calculus, it is to prove that $$x^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ is decreasing when $x\ge e$, which is also not hard.

Comment: A little mistake $n^3=(n-1)^3+3(n-1)^2+3(n-1)+1<(n-1)^3+3(n-1)^2+3(n-1)+3$

Comment: @user19405892 sorry. How about now?

Comment: There was nothing wrong with your original inequality. If $3<n$ then  $3<n^2$ therefore $3(n+1)^2+1<(n+1)^3+3$.

Comment: I meant except for the mistake pointed out by @ArnaldoNascimento. You only had to change the $+3$ on the left of the inequality to $+1$ which I assumed was merely a typo.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes, thanks. I am sorry that I was not careful.

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$\sqrt[n]{m} > \sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\sqrt[m]{n} > \sqrt[3]{3}$.

Expressed using fractional powers, these are precisely:
${m^{1/n}} > {3^{1/3}}$ and ${n^{1/m}} > {3^{1/3}}$.

Taking *n*th and *m*th powers respectively, we get:
${m > 3^{n/3}}$ and ${n > 3^{m/3}}$.

Substitute for *m* from the first inequality in the second:
${n > 3^{{3^{n/3}}/3}}$.

Simplifying the exponent:
${n > 3^{3^{(n-3)/3}}}$.

Could this be true for all *n*?  Take, for example, *n*=303, giving:
${303 > 3^{3^{100}}}$
which is patently false.  So we have our contradiction.

[**Edit**]  Of course, the above merely shows that for **some** *m*, there exist values of *n* for which the two roots *n*^(1/*m*) and *m*^(1/*n*) can't both exceed 3^(1/3).  However, I think we should read the original question as asking us to show that for **every pair** of integers *m*, *n* both > 1, with each integer being chosen **independently** of the other, those two roots can't both exceed 3^(1/3).  The reasoning I gave showed much less than that!  Although I've since tried other approaches, I now believe that the only other *Answer* to date, by user [**S. Y**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/364140/s-y), uses probably the best and simplest approach.